# Year-wise citation in text with apalike bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apa-style

I have a code like this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{mathptmx,amssymb,hyperref}
\usepackage[square,sort&compress]{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=15mm,bottom=22mm,left=30mm,right=20mm,textwidth=160mm,textheight=245mm,headheight=3mm,headsep=12mm,footskip=10mm}
\begin{document}
There is extensive study by many 
\citep{Gurnett1978,Scarf1979,Lee1981,Lin2001,Hellberg2002,Sultana2010}.
\bibliography{document_citation}
\end{document}
```

The corresponding bib file is:

```
@Article{Gurnett1978,
  author  = {Gurnett, D. A. and Frank, L. A.},
  journal = {J. Geophys. Res- Space},
  year    = {1978},
  doi     = {10.1029/JA083iA01p00058},
}
@Article{Hellberg2002,
  author  = {Hellberg,M. A. and Mace, R. L.},
  journal = {Phys. Plasmas},
  year    = {2002},
  doi     = {10.1063/1.1462636},
}
@Article{Lee1981,
  author  = {Lee, L. C. and Kan, J. R.},
  journal = {Phys. Fluids},
  year    = {1981},
  doi     = {10.1063/1.863389},
}
@Article{Lin2001,
  author  = {Lin, N. and Kellogg, P.J. and MacDowall, R.J. and Gary, S.P.},
  journal = {Space Sci. Rev.},
  year    = {2001},
  doi     = {10.1023/A:1011823505395},
}
@Article{Sultana2010,
  author  = {Sultana, S. and Kourakis, I. and Saini, N. S. and Hellberg, M. A.},
  journal = {Phys. Plasmas},
  year    = {2010},
  doi     = {10.1063/1.3322895},
}
@Article{Scarf1979,
  author  = {Scarf, F. L. And Gurnett, D. A. And Kurth, W. S.},
  journal = {Science},
  year    = {1979},
  doi     = {10.1126/science.204.4396.991},
}
```

I am using bibliography style apalike, which sorts the bibliography in alphabetical order. But in text I would like to see it in the chronological year. This was the motivation why I wrote it like \citep{Gurnett1978,Scarf1979,Lee1981,Lin2001,Hellberg2002,Sultana2010}, but as you can see the end product is [Gurnett and Frank, 1978; Hellberg and Mace, 2002; Lee and Kan, 1981; Lin et al., 2001; Scarf et al., 1979; Sultana et al., 2010] which is in alphabetical order.
[image: Snapshot]

Is there any way to cite the articles in year-wise in text, but still arrange the article in alphabetical order in the Bibliography page?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You can leave out the `sort&compress` option to `natbib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn off sorting, do not include the `sort&compress` option for `natbib`. (By the way, for author year citations, `sort&compress` does the same thing as `sort.)

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Gurnett1978,
  author  = {Gurnett, D. A. and Frank, L. A.},
  journal = {J. Geophys. Res- Space},
  year    = {1978},
  doi     = {10.1029/JA083iA01p00058},
}
@Article{Hellberg2002,
  author  = {Hellberg,M. A. and Mace, R. L.},
  journal = {Phys. Plasmas},
  year    = {2002},
  doi     = {10.1063/1.1462636},
}
@Article{Lee1981,
  author  = {Lee, L. C. and Kan, J. R.},
  journal = {Phys. Fluids},
  year    = {1981},
  doi     = {10.1063/1.863389},
}
@Article{Lin2001,
  author  = {Lin, N. and Kellogg, P.J. and MacDowall, R.J. and Gary, S.P.},
  journal = {Space Sci. Rev.},
  year    = {2001},
  doi     = {10.1023/A:1011823505395},
}
@Article{Sultana2010,
  author  = {Sultana, S. and Kourakis, I. and Saini, N. S. and Hellberg, M. A.},
  journal = {Phys. Plasmas},
  year    = {2010},
  doi     = {10.1063/1.3322895},
}
@Article{Scarf1979,
  author  = {Scarf, F. L. And Gurnett, D. A. And Kurth, W. S.},
  journal = {Science},
  year    = {1979},
  doi     = {10.1126/science.204.4396.991},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[square]{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\begin{document}
There is extensive study by many 
\citep{Gurnett1978,Scarf1979,Lee1981,Lin2001,Hellberg2002,Sultana2010}.
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot ... I didn't know it.. It indeed worked...