# In-text citation sorted according to publication year with apalike bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib, apa-style, sorting

I am using the `natbib` bibtex package with the [authoryear,compress] options and the bibliographystyle `apalike`. Is it possible to modify the `natbib` package options so that in-text citations are ordered according to the publication year?

The same question has already been asked here:
[Year-wise citation in text with apalike bibliography style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452694/year-wise-citation-in-text-with-apalike-bibliography-style)

The accepted answer is only a workaround if your bibtex-keys in your `\citep{}` command are already in the correct order (you just avoid the `sort&compress` option), though. But if you want them ordered automatically according to the publication year (without manually providing the correct sorting in the `\citep{}` command, this answer does not solve the issue.

Is there a solution to this? The answer here (last paragraph) sounds a little bit as if this is not possible (?):
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62411/112395

To give a worked example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,hidelinks]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[authoryear,compress]{natbib}        %Calls bibliography commands + Cite with author-year style (Harvard) instead of the numeric style. Let's just use compress instead of sort&compress: Note, however, that this means that the ordering of the in-text references follows the order you specified in the text (i. e., no automatical sorting is carried out!)



\begin{document}

%

\section*{References}
\label{sec:References}
\citep{Owen1876,
Berman1977,
Berman1987,
Berman1992,
Berman1993,
Berman1993_Seymouria,
Berman2003_Aspidosaurus,
Berman2004,
Berman2010_Fedexia,
Berman2011_Rotaryus,
Berman2014,
Berman2015}


\citep{Berman1977,
Berman1987,
Berman1992,
Berman1993,
Berman1993_Seymouria,
Berman2003_Aspidosaurus,
Berman2004,
Berman2010_Fedexia,
Berman2011_Rotaryus,
Berman2014,
Berman2015,
Owen1876}





\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{myrefs}


\end{document}
```

with the following myref.bib file:

```
@Book{Owen1876,
  title     = {{Descriptive and illustrated catalogue of the Fossil Reptilia of South Africa in the collection of the British Museum}},
  publisher = {British Museum (Natural History)},
  year      = {1876},
  author    = {Richard Owen},
  address   = {London, United Kingdom},
  note      = {88 pp.},
  url       = {http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k987042},
}

@Article{Berman1977,
  author    = {Berman, David S},
  title     = {{A new species of \textit{Dimetrodon} (Reptilia, Pelycosauria) from a non-deltaic facies in the Lower Permian of north-central New Mexico}},
  journal   = {Journal of Paleontology},
  year      = {1977},
  volume    = {51},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {108--115},
}

@Article{Berman1987,
  author    = {David S. Berman and Robert R. Reisz and David A. Eberth},
  title     = {{\textit{Seymouria sanjuanensis} (Amphibia, Batrachosauria) from the Lower Permian Cutler Formation of north-central New {Mexico} and the occurrence of sexual dimorphism in that genus questioned}},
  journal   = {Canadian Journal of Earth Sciences},
  year      = {1987},
  volume    = {24},
  number    = {9},
  pages     = {1769--1784},
}

@Article{Berman1992,
  author    = {David S. Berman and Stuart S. Sumida and R. Eric Lombard},
  title     = {{Reinterpretation of the temporal and occipital regions in \textit{Diadectes} and the relationships of diadectomorphs}},
  journal   = {Journal of Paleontology},
  year      = {1992},
  volume    = {66},
  number    = {3},
  pages     = {481--499},
}

@InCollection{Berman1993,
  author    = {Berman, D. S.},
  title     = {{Lower Permian vertebrate localities of New Mexico and their assemblages}},
  booktitle = {{Vertebrate Paleontology in New Mexico}},
  publisher = {New Mexico Museum of Natural History},
  year      = {1993},
  editor    = {Spencer G. Lucas AND Jiri Zidek},
  volume    = {2},
  pages     = {11--21},
}

@Article{Berman1993_Seymouria,
  author   = {Berman, David S. and Martens, Thomas},
  title    = {{First occurrence of \textit{Seymouria} (Amphibia: Batrachosauria) in the Lower Permian Rotliegend of central Germany}},
  journal  = {Annals of Carnegie Museum},
  year     = {1993},
  volume   = {62},
  number   = {1},
  pages    = {63--79},
}

@Article{Berman2003_Aspidosaurus,
  author   = {Berman, David S. and Lucas, Spencer G.},
  title    = {{\textit{Aspidosaurus binasser} (Amphibia, Temnospondyli), a new species of Dissorophidae from the Lower Permian of Texas}},
  journal  = {Annals of Carnegie Museum},
  year     = {2003},
  volume   = {72},
  number   = {4},
  pages    = {241--262},
}

@Article{Berman2004,
  author    = {Berman, David S and Henrici, Amy C and Sumida, Stuart S and Martens, Thomas},
  title     = {{New materials of \textit{Dimetrodon teutonis} (Synapsida: Sphenacodontidae) from the Lower Permian of Germany}},
  journal   = {Annals of Carnegie Museum},
  year      = {2004},
  volume    = {73},
  number    = {2},
  pages     = {48--56},
}

@Article{Berman2010_Fedexia,
  author    = {David S Berman and Amy C. Henrici and David K. Brezinski and Albert D. Kollar},
  title     = {{A new trematopid amphibian (Temnospondyli: Dissorophoidea) from the Upper Pennsylvanian of Western Pennsylvania: earliest record of terrestrial vertebrates responding to a warmer, drier climate}},
  journal   = {Annals of Carnegie Museum},
  year      = {2010},
  volume    = {78},
  number    = {4},
  pages     = {289--318},
}

@Article{Berman2011_Rotaryus,
  author    = {David S Berman and Amy C. Henrici and Thomas Martens and Stuart S. Sumida and Jason S. Anderson},
  title     = {{\textit{Rotaryus gothae}, a new trematopid (Temnospondyli: Dissorophoidea) from the Lower Permian of central {Germany}}},
  journal   = {Annals of Carnegie Museum},
  year      = {2011},
  volume    = {80},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {49--65},
}

@InCollection{Berman2014,
  author    = {Berman, David S and Henrici, Amy C. and Sumida, Stuart S. and Martens, Thomas and Pelletier, Valerie},
  title     = {{First European Record of a Varanodontine (Synapsida: Varanopidae): Member of a Unique Early Permian Upland Paleoecosystem, Tambach Basin, Central Germany}},
  booktitle = {{Early Evolutionary History of the Synapsida}},
  publisher = {Springer},
  year      = {2014},
  editor    = {Kammerer, Christian F. and Angielczyk, Kenneth D. and Fr{\"o}bisch, J{\"o}rg},
  series    = {Vertebrate Paleobiology and Paleoanthropology},
  chapter   = {5},
  pages     = {69--86},
  address   = {Dordrecht},
}

@InCollection{Berman2015,
  author    = {David S. Berman AND Amy C. Henrici AND Spencer G. Lucas},
  title     = {{Pennsylvanian-Permian Red Bed vertebrate localities of New Mexico an their assemblages}},
  booktitle = {{Fossil Vertebrates in New Mexico}},
  publisher = {New Mexico Museum of Natural History},
  year      = {2015},
  editor    = {Lucas, S. G. AND Sullivan, R. M.},
  volume    = {68},
  pages     = {65--76},
}
```

This will produce the following in-text citation:
[image]

As you can see, in the second citation the references are not in chronological order: the one from 1876 appears last instead of appearing first. Is there a way to change this (without having to manually go through all the `\cite` commands)?

Preferably I would like to see a solution using bibtex, not biblatex.

Comment: As far as I understand `natbib`'s `sort` option sorts citations with multiple keys in the order they appear in the bibliography/list of references. So unless your bibliography is sorted by year first you can't easily get the order you want in the citations. (Since you mention `biblatex`, it would be possible there: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361031/35864, but can have very bad side-effects so that I would not recommend it even there.)

Comment: Indeed, `natbib`'s `sort` command sorts citations with multiple keys in the order they appear in the bibliography. In my case they are sorted alphabetically (well actually, it is a bit more complicated - I am using the custom BST you helped me with: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484079/112395; but I did not want to make my request more complicated/confusing so I omitted this).
Is there no way to achieve the chronological ordering in bibtex using `natbib`and/or a modified version of `natbib`? You would think that other people faced the same problem before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware `natbib`'s `sort` option sorts by the order in the bibliography. So the automatic sorting can only get you the order you would have in the bibliography.

Here is a proof of concept that tries to produce a different sorting in the citations than for the bibliography.

It works as follows: The `.bst` file produces a bibliography as always. But then afterwards it sorts all entries again in the desired citation order and writes the order information into the `.bbl` file. This order information is read, written to the `.aux` and finally results in a sorted list of all entry keys in the desired citation order.

We then modify the internal definition of the `\cite` command to sort all entries with our list of sorted keys. This is more or less how `biblatex` sorts its citations.

Hence, you will need a modified `.bst` file. For `apalike.bst` as in the example it is enough to add

```
FUNCTION {sort.again}
{
  year field.or.null sortify
  "   "
  * 
  sort.label
  *
  'sort.key$ :=
}

ITERATE {sort.again}

SORT

EXECUTE {newline$}

FUNCTION {produce.sortlist}
{
  "\sortentry{"
  cite$
  *
  "}"
  *
  write$
  newline$
}

ITERATE {produce.sortlist}
```

at the end of the file to obtain the sorting information. YMMV with different styles. Assume the new style is called `apalike-citesort.bst`. You can download it from https://gist.github.com/moewew/22e70d3c0c6df24859bf949a44bffb62.

The MWE shows the necessary redefinitions of the cite macro. I had the feeling that it should have been simpler to trick `natbib` into using the new citation list, but in the end I had to use a less pretty route.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\sortentry}[1]{%
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\uNAT@aux@sortentry{#1}}%
  \fi}
\newcommand*{\uNAT@aux@sortentry}{%
  \listgadd{\uNAT@bibsortlist}}
\newcommand*{\uNAT@bibsortlist}{}


\newcommand*{\uNAT@citekeys}{}

\newcommand*{\uNAT@writetocitelistsort}[1]{%
  \ifinlist{#1}{\uNAT@citekeys}
    {\ifdefvoid{\NAT@cite@list}
       {\def\NAT@cite@list{#1}}
       {\expandafter\def\expandafter\NAT@cite@list\expandafter{\NAT@cite@list,#1}}%
     \listgadd{\uNAT@foundkeys}{#1}}
    {}}

% Let's be paranoid: we might have dropped an item that
% has not made it to the bibliography yet
\newcommand*{\uNAT@writetocitelistforgotten}[1]{%
  \ifinlist{#1}{\uNAT@foundkeys}
    {}
    {\ifdefvoid{\NAT@cite@list}
       {\def\NAT@cite@list{#1}}
       {\expandafter\def\expandafter\NAT@cite@list\expandafter{\NAT@cite@list,#1}}}}

\newcommand*{\uNAT@sortcites}[1]{%
  \let\NAT@cite@list\@empty
  \let\uNAT@citekeys\@empty
  \let\uNAT@foundkeys\@empty
  \forcsvlist{\listadd{\uNAT@citekeys}}{#1}%
  \forlistloop{\uNAT@writetocitelistsort}{\uNAT@bibsortlist}%
  \forlistloop{\uNAT@writetocitelistforgotten}{\uNAT@citekeys}%
}

\def\NAT@citex%
  [#1][#2]#3{%
  \NAT@reset@parser
  \NAT@sort@cites{#3}%
  \uNAT@sortcites{#3}%<- this is new
  \NAT@reset@citea
  \@cite{\let\NAT@nm\@empty\let\NAT@year\@empty
    \@for\@citeb:=\NAT@cite@list\do
    {\@safe@activestrue
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \@safe@activesfalse
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}{\@citea%
       {\reset@font\bfseries ?}\NAT@citeundefined
                 \PackageWarning{natbib}%
       {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}\def\NAT@date{}}%
     {\let\NAT@last@nm=\NAT@nm\let\NAT@last@yr=\NAT@year
      \NAT@parse{\@citeb}%
      \ifNAT@longnames\@ifundefined{bv@\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}{%
        \let\NAT@name=\NAT@all@names
        \global\@namedef{bv@\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}{}}{}%
      \fi
     \ifNAT@full\let\NAT@nm\NAT@all@names\else
       \let\NAT@nm\NAT@name\fi
     \ifNAT@swa\ifcase\NAT@ctype
       \if\relax\NAT@date\relax
         \@citea\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}\NAT@date}%
       \else
         \ifx\NAT@last@nm\NAT@nm\NAT@yrsep
            \ifx\NAT@last@yr\NAT@year
              \def\NAT@temp{{?}}%
              \ifx\NAT@temp\NAT@exlab\PackageWarningNoLine{natbib}%
               {Multiple citation on page \thepage: same authors and
               year\MessageBreak without distinguishing extra
               letter,\MessageBreak appears as question mark}\fi
              \NAT@hyper@{\NAT@exlab}%
            \else\unskip\NAT@spacechar
              \NAT@hyper@{\NAT@date}%
            \fi
         \else
           \@citea\NAT@hyper@{%
             \NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}%
             \hyper@natlinkbreak{%
               \NAT@aysep\NAT@spacechar}{\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb
             }%
             \NAT@date
           }%
         \fi
       \fi
     \or\@citea\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}}%
     \or\@citea\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@date}%
     \or\@citea\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@alias}%
     \fi \NAT@def@citea
     \else
       \ifcase\NAT@ctype
        \if\relax\NAT@date\relax
          \@citea\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}}%
        \else
         \ifx\NAT@last@nm\NAT@nm\NAT@yrsep
            \ifx\NAT@last@yr\NAT@year
              \def\NAT@temp{{?}}%
              \ifx\NAT@temp\NAT@exlab\PackageWarningNoLine{natbib}%
               {Multiple citation on page \thepage: same authors and
               year\MessageBreak without distinguishing extra
               letter,\MessageBreak appears as question mark}\fi
              \NAT@hyper@{\NAT@exlab}%
            \else
              \unskip\NAT@spacechar
              \NAT@hyper@{\NAT@date}%
            \fi
         \else
           \@citea\NAT@hyper@{%
             \NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}%
             \hyper@natlinkbreak{\NAT@spacechar\NAT@@open\if*#1*\else#1\NAT@spacechar\fi}%
               {\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}%
             \NAT@date
           }%
         \fi
        \fi
       \or\@citea\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}}%
       \or\@citea\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@date}%
       \or\@citea\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@alias}%
       \fi
       \if\relax\NAT@date\relax
         \NAT@def@citea
       \else
         \NAT@def@citea@close
       \fi
     \fi
     }}\ifNAT@swa\else\if*#2*\else\NAT@cmt#2\fi
     \if\relax\NAT@date\relax\else\NAT@@close\fi\fi}{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Owen1876,
  title     = {{Descriptive and illustrated catalogue of the Fossil Reptilia of South Africa in the collection of the British Museum}},
  publisher = {British Museum (Natural History)},
  year      = {1876},
  author    = {Richard Owen},
  address   = {London, United Kingdom},
  note      = {88 pp.},
  url       = {http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k987042},
}
@article{Berman1977,
  author    = {Berman, David S},
  title     = {{A new species of \textit{Dimetrodon} (Reptilia, Pelycosauria) from a non-deltaic facies in the Lower Permian of north-central New Mexico}},
  journal   = {Journal of Paleontology},
  year      = {1977},
  volume    = {51},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {108--115},
}
@article{Berman1993_Seymouria,
  author   = {Berman, David S. and Martens, Thomas},
  title    = {{First occurrence of \textit{Seymouria} (Amphibia: Batrachosauria) in the Lower Permian Rotliegend of central Germany}},
  journal  = {Annals of Carnegie Museum},
  year     = {1993},
  volume   = {62},
  number   = {1},
  pages    = {63--79},
}
@incollection{Berman2015,
  author    = {David S. Berman AND Amy C. Henrici AND Spencer G. Lucas},
  title     = {{Pennsylvanian-Permian Red Bed vertebrate localities of New Mexico an their assemblages}},
  booktitle = {{Fossil Vertebrates in New Mexico}},
  publisher = {New Mexico Museum of Natural History},
  year      = {2015},
  editor    = {Lucas, S. G. AND Sullivan, R. M.},
  volume    = {68},
  pages     = {65--76},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\citep{Owen1876,
Berman1977,
Berman1993_Seymouria,
Berman2015}

\citep{Berman1977,
Berman1993_Seymouria,
Berman2015,
Owen1876}

\bibliographystyle{apalike-citesort}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Citations in year order]

Comment: Thank you very much! I can confirm that this works for my MWE - it even works, when using other `\cite` commands like `\citet` or `\citealp`.

Unfortunately, for my actual document it does not work. Initially I thought that this was because I already tried to define a new cite command like so:

`%Cite with 's
\newcommand\cites[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s\ (\citeyear{#1})}`

This gives an error, if the new command generated by your proposal is not inserted after my new command.

Continue below.

Comment: But even when the command order is reversed, the complete PDF generation is not possible - or rather it is possible only to a certain extent. I can compile the document + run bibtex + get a PDF, but my Latex editor (Texmaker) will hang when I try to get the references in the bibliography linked to the in-text references (which therefore appear as "?").

I will have to figure out, why that is the case. Since this is not directly linked to my question, I will just wait some time to see whether someone else comes up with a different solution. If not, I will accept your answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user6475 Mhhh, in a short test based on my MWE I can get you `\cites` to work more or less as I expected. Can you upload an MWE to https://pastebin.com/ or a similar text-sharing website that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Thank you for your continuous help! I will try and see, whether I can generate an appropriate MWE. Unfortunately, the original document is about 500 pages long (with hundreds of references) and quite complicated with various chapters that are coerced to a single document by a master file. Furthermore, it also contains confidential information which I am currently not allowed to share (otherwise I could just upload everything). So it might take a while for me to figure out, what is actually causing the issue here. As you say, it is almost certainly not the `\cites` command.